# Getting "Uncaught TypeError: can't convert undefined to object" error when asking for data in firebase firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have this function that gets data from Firebase Firestore

```
function getEventData(eventNumber) {
    firebase.firestore().collection('events').document(eventNumber).get().then((doc) => {
        if(doc.exists){
            console.log("Document data:\n", doc.data());
        } else {
            console.log("Document doesn't exist.");
        }
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error: ", error);
    });
}
```

And when i execute it i get "Uncaught TypeError: can't convert undefined to object" as error

Comment: something in there is undefined - `eventNumber` seems to be the likliest - how are you calling `getEventData`?

Comment: Inside a function that gets executed on page load:
```getEventData('1');```

Comment: I get the same error even if i try calling it in the console or if i just type ```firebase.firestore().collection('events').document('1');```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing `document` to `doc`

```js
function getEventData(eventNumber) {
    firebase.firestore().collection('events').doc(eventNumber).get().then((doc) => {
        if(doc.exists){
            console.log("Document data:\n", doc.data());
        } else {
            console.log("Document doesn't exist.");
        }
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error: ", error);
    });
}
```